# How do i wait for promises to get resolved?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, firebase-storage

```
    try {
              (async ()=> await Promise.all(this.state.selectedFile.map(picture =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  Firebase.getStorageRef(`/${picture.name}`)
                    .put(picture)
                    .on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
                      // progress function ....
                      const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
                      console.log("Progress: ", progress)
                    },
                    reject,
                    () => {
                      // complete function .... 
                      Firebase.getStorageRef(`/${picture}`)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url => {
                      this.setState({mage:this.state.mage.concat([url])})
                      console.log(this.state.mage,"yooo")
                    });
                });
              })
          )).then( Firebase.getDatabaseRef().push({
                  
                  image:[this.state.mage],
     
                  thumbImage:[this.state.mage]
                
                }).then(()=>{
                  console.log("added")
                })))();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
```

In the above code,a list of images are being uploaded using the Promise. All method which when each image is being uploaded uses the `.then()` method to store the url in a list to pass it on to another `.then()` that stores it in a database.

**Error:**

The url of the image is null as it is getting executed before the upload finishes.

Isnt the `.then()` method is responsible to execute after the upload is done?

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a custom promise with `return Promise((resolve, reject) => {`, but you then never call `resolve`. This means that your promise never resolves, and hence the `then` of the `Promise.all()` method never gets called.

I don't think you need a custom promise though, as `put` already returns a promise that you can use.

I'd start with something like this:

```
const promises = this.state.selectedFile.map(picture => {
  const ref = Firebase.getStorageRef(`/${picture.name}`);
  return ref
    .put(picture)
    .then(() => ref.getDownloadURL());
});
Promise.all((downloadUrls) => {
  this.setState({ mage: downloadUrls })
  Firebase.getDatabaseRef().push({
    image: downloadUrls
  })
})
```

*Note that I didn't run the above code, so there may be minor errors in it. If you get such errors, please try to fix them by searching for the error message.*

Comment: Hey Frank,in the above code the list of pictures gets asynchronously added to the database and returns  promises of each URL.How are you refferring to each individual promise returned by the map function in the Promise.all to store all the URLs in a state array?

Comment: I'm setting all URLs to the state and database at once, after all the uploads and calls to `getDownloadURL`s are done. If you want to do this per individual upload that completes, you'll need to modify the code for that. The problem in your code is still the same as what I point out in the first paragraph of my answer in that case.